# Remove Close Button | Facebook Page Promoter Lightbox

Tags: plugins

Good day! I want to remove the close button in this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-page-promoter-lightbox/).

[image]

I think it's in *\includes\featherlight\featherlight.css* but I'm not sure where and what to edit. Even if deleting the image won't do. Sorry! Newbie here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit your theme style.css file.It will remove close button.

```
span.ArevicoModal-close-icon.ArevicoModal-close{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: never ever edit plugin files unless you are happy with not getting any support from the author

Comment: @Mark Kaplun [Sorry!](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-close-button/)

Comment: As the author I would also like to add that i don't condone,  nor support removing the close button